# AWS Serverless Offline Invoke function show 2015-03-31

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, serverless

I created a serverless nodejs typescript project from template. When I start up the app in offline mode I see 2 end-points.

- What is the second end-point (Invoke)?
- how is it generated?
- What does 2015-03-31 date specify?
- It shows POST when I changed the original end-point to GET

[image: VS Code Terminal]